# Can I delete by attribute in Amazon SimpleDB without specifying an ItemName?

Tags: amazon-simpledb

Can I delete by attribute in SimpleDB without providing an ItemName parameter in the query string? The way I store my data is the item names are UUIDs, so I don't know the UUID of the data I want to delete. Is there a way to just specify an attribute and have it delete all items with that attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to delete without the item name, but you can use a SELECT to get the items to be deleted:

```
select itemName() from MyDomain where MyAttribute = 'foo'
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to do 2 queries so I switched away from UUIDs. This is exactly what I was looking for though, thanks!